# Linker error LNK2019 from 3rd party library

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am porting an old vc++6.0 application to vs2005, I am getting the following linker error and I have spent days trying to find a solution.

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_CreateAwnService@52
>   referenced in function "public: int __thiscall
>   CMainFrame::CreateAsaNetworkServices(void)"

There is a 3rd party C library with the following API defined

```
extern "C"
{
DLLAPI IAwnServ * AWNAPI CreateAwnService(HINSTANCE hInst,
    const char *pszDId, const char *pszDLoc,
    AWN_DIQUAL DiQual, AWN_DOQUAL DoQual, int Prio,
    const char *pszLicStr, const char *pszInfo,
    AWN_REPEAT Repeat=R_LAST, TIME_T Since=0,
    BOOL bLogin=FALSE, BOOL bDeb=FALSE);

DLLAPI IAwnSend * AWNAPI CreateAwnSend(const IAwnSend *pSend = NULL);
DLLAPI IAwnData * AWNAPI CreateAwnData(const char *pData = NULL, int iLen = 0);
DLLAPI IAwnHeader * AWNAPI CreateAwnHeader(const IAwnHeader *pHeader = NULL);
DLLAPI IAwnReference * AWNAPI CreateAwnReference(const IAwnReference *pRef = NULL);
DLLAPI IAwnFile * AWNAPI CreateAwnFile(const char *pFile = NULL);
DLLAPI IAwnOrder * AWNAPI CreateAwnOrder( const IAwnOrder *pOrder);
DLLAPI IAwnVehicle * AWNAPI CreateAwnVehicle( const IAwnVehicle *pVehicle);

DLLAPI int AWNAPI AwnCmp( const IAwnSend *pSend1, const IAwnSend *pSend2);

DLLAPI TIME_T AWNAPI AwnGetNetTime( const char *NetTime);
DLLAPI int AWNAPI AwnSetNetTime( char *NetTime, TIME_T Time);
DLLAPI TIME_T AWNAPI AwnMakeQueryTime( int MonthsBack);
DLLAPI struct tm *AWNAPI AwnSplitTime( TIME_T Time);
DLLAPI TIME_T AWNAPI AwnMakeTime( tm *ptm);
}

#endif
```

The call to the API is as follows:

```
m_pIAwnService = CreateAwnService( AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance, .........)
```

I have checked all links includes etc and I cant seem to find the error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, the error is in the linker options. *It always is*. You may have checked, but maybe you didn't check everything, or didn't check right.

Comment: are you sure 3rd-party library is linked successfully?

Comment: @ R. Martinho Fernandes can u suggest some linker settings to check.

Comment: @user: sorry, I don't have VC6, and I haven't used it in a while, so I can't give you the exact locations of the settings, but you should look for something like "library search directories" and "library dependencies".

Comment: @  R. Martinho Fernandes  added it to Additional Library Dependencies, still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the import library for the dll, or the linker cannot find it, in the Linker -> Input -> Additional dependancies

The library paths can be set in Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories

It may be that the header files try to automatically include the lib file using a #pragma, so you should again check that the linker can find the file.

Another thing to check would be to look at the DLL using dependancy walker and make sure the function you are trying to use really is @52 for the stack cleanup size. Perhaps the sizes of variable types have changed between the compiler versions (for e.g. the typedefs).

Comment: Libraries are set in the Additional dependencies under Linker Input

Comment: I have checked the DLL wil Dependency Walker and you are right _CreateAwnService is at 48 not at 52 as the output suggests how is this fixed.

Comment: @user655261: What about the DLL function in dependany walker? It could be caused by the TIME_T definition (if it defined as time_t), as that changed from 32 bit to 64 bit in VS2005 (IIRC).

Comment: @user655261: Apologies for missing your previous comment. You need to define _USE_32BIT_TIME_T in your project. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4ddyt9h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx. However, you should check the sizes of each parameter type in VC6 to make sure what size they are meant to be.

Comment: _USE_32BIT_TIME_T did not work as it broke other parts of the code but it put me on the right track the only change that was required was in the method signature for CreateAwnService change TIME_T to __time32_t and everything works

Answer (score 0):

Is DLLAPI macro defined to `__declspec(dllimport)` when you build your application?

Comment: Yes its defined as follows                                                #    ifdef _BUILD_AWN_DLL_
    #      define DLLAPI  __declspec(dllexport)
    #    else
    #      define DLLAPI  __declspec(dllimport)
    #    endif

Answer (score 0):

If you *do* miss import library for your DLL, take a look at this MSDN article: [How To Create 32-bit Import Libraries Without .OBJs or Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/131313).
This way you can make a load-time dynamic linking of third-party DLL for which you do not have import library supplied.

Comment: @DuKes0mE - Sad thing that Internet sites die...Corrected MSDN link, though, because some of them are still alive. And that is a good thing.